# Julia unusable because of Grisu dependency

Tags: package, dependencies, julia

I just installed the latest fresh Julia (1.7.3). Afterwards I installed some packages for optimization.

Inbetween Julia started to report an unresolvable dependency on package Grisu. Now a lot of the installed packaged don't work:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: Grisu not defined
```

What problem is this with Julia? Do I need to un- and reinstall the entire Julia system or is there a workaround for this? I don't need Grisu but packages that depend on Grisu.

I also tried to remove the packages that don't compile (to reinstall afterwards), e.g.

```
julia> Pkg.rm("JuMP")
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * JuMP (4076af6c-e467-56ae-b986-b466b2749572 in manifest but not in project)
```

but after

```
julia>  Pkg.precompile()
```

I get

```
julia>  Pkg.precompile()
Precompiling project...
  ✗ Interpolations
  ✗ JuMP
  ✗ Alpine
  ✗ JuMPeR
  ✗ Pajarito
  ✗ MultiJuMP
  ✗ NLOptControl
```

so the package JuMP (e.g.) is still there and failes to compile.

What is wrong here?

EDIT:

```
julia> Pkg.build()
    Building GR ───────→ `C:\Users\Michael\.julia\scratchspaces\44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f\7ea6f715b7caa10d7ee16f1cfcd12f3ccc74116a\build.log`
    Building Conda ────→ `C:\Users\Michael\.julia\scratchspaces\44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f\6e47d11ea2776bc5627421d59cdcc1296c058071\build.log`
    Building IJulia ───→ `C:\Users\Michael\.julia\scratchspaces\44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f\98ab633acb0fe071b671f6c1785c46cd70bb86bd\build.log`
    Building OptimPack → `C:\Users\Michael\.julia\scratchspaces\44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f\6c8a57b7abf98250755764fe49138781c09d6826\build.log`
    Building Plots ────→ `C:\Users\Michael\.julia\scratchspaces\44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f\f226ff9b8e391f6a10891563c370aae8beb5d792\build.log`
Precompiling project...
  ✗ NLOptControl
  1 dependency successfully precompiled in 35 seconds (224 already precompiled, 5 skipped during auto due to previous errors)
  1 dependency errored. To see a full report either run `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` or load the package

julia> import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()
Precompiling project...
  ✗ JuMP
  ✗ Alpine
  ✗ JuMPeR
  ✗ Pajarito
  ✗ MultiJuMP
  ✗ NLOptControl
  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 11 seconds (225 already precompiled)

ERROR: The following 5 direct dependencies failed to precompile:

Pajarito [2f354839-79df-5901-9f0a-cdb2aac6fe30]

Failed to precompile Pajarito [2f354839-79df-5901-9f0a-cdb2aac6fe30] to C:\Users\Michael\.julia\compiled\v1.7\Pajarito\jl_3088.tmp.
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: Grisu not defined
Stacktrace:
  [1] getproperty(x::Module, f::Symbol)
    @ Base .\Base.jl:35
  [2] top-level scope
    @ C:\Users\Michael\.julia\packages\JuMP\I7whV\src\writers.jl:6
  [3] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base .\Base.jl:418
  [4] include(x::String)
    @ JuMP C:\Users\Michael\.julia\packages\JuMP\I7whV\src\JuMP.jl:11
  [5] top-level scope
    @ C:\Users\Michael\.julia\packages\JuMP\I7whV\src\JuMP.jl:947
  [6] include
    @ .\Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [7] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1318
  [8] top-level scope
    @ none:1
  [9] eval
    @ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [10] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:453
 [11] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\Michael\.julia\packages\JuMP\I7whV\src\writers.jl:5
in expression starting at C:\Users\Michael\.julia\packages\JuMP\I7whV\src\JuMP.jl:11
```

EDIT 2:

After removing .julia and reinstalling JuMPeR and MultiJuMP the same happend. The later caused the following:

```
    Updating `C:\Users\Michael\.julia\environments\v1.7\Project.toml`
  [07493b3f] ↓ Alpine v0.4.1 ⇒ v0.1.15
  [4076af6c] ↓ JuMP v1.1.1 ⇒ v0.18.6
  [f6097e2c] + MultiJuMP v0.5.0
  [2f354839] ↓ Pajarito v0.8.0 ⇒ v0.7.0
    Updating `C:\Users\Michael\.julia\environments\v1.7\Manifest.toml`
  [07493b3f] ↓ Alpine v0.4.1 ⇒ v0.1.15
  [6e4b80f9] - BenchmarkTools v1.3.1
  [523fee87] - CodecBzip2 v0.7.2
  [944b1d66] - CodecZlib v0.7.0
  [861a8166] + Combinatorics v0.7.0
  [34da2185] ↓ Compat v4.1.0 ⇒ v2.2.1
  [e95a7839] + ConicBenchmarkUtilities v0.4.0
  [864edb3b] ↓ DataStructures v0.18.13 ⇒ v0.17.20
  [92fee26a] + GZip v0.5.1
  [682c06a0] - JSON v0.21.3
  [4076af6c] ↓ JuMP v1.1.1 ⇒ v0.18.6
  [b964fa9f] + LaTeXStrings v1.3.0
  [b8f27783] - MathOptInterface v1.6.0
  [fdba3010] + MathProgBase v0.7.8
  [f6097e2c] + MultiJuMP v0.5.0
  [d8a4904e] - MutableArithmetics v1.0.4
  [77ba4419] ↓ NaNMath v1.0.1 ⇒ v0.3.7
  [2f354839] ↓ Pajarito v0.8.0 ⇒ v0.7.0
  [69de0a69] - Parsers v2.3.2
  [f27b6e38] + Polynomials v0.6.1
  [3cdcf5f2] + RecipesBase v0.8.0
  [89212889] + ReverseDiffSparse v0.8.6
  [3bb67fe8] - TranscodingStreams v0.9.6
  [6e34b625] - Bzip2_jll v1.0.8+0
  [8bb1440f] + DelimitedFiles
  [8ba89e20] + Distributed
  [9abbd945] - Profile
  [1a1011a3] + SharedArrays
Precompiling project...
  ✗ JuMP
  ✗ Alpine
  ✗ Pajarito
  ✗ MultiJuMP
```

Afterwards it is not possible to repair the packages, even by uninstalling the problematic packages.

Comment: Oh, this is merely a dependent package that is installed. If you install Package `A` and internally that uses packages `B` and `C` then these are )only) installed as dependent packages. You can only delete `B` here by deleting all packages that internally use `B` (such as `A`.

Comment: Can you maybe help by stating which packages you wandet to use?
Usually – continuing from the previous comment – it might happen, that `A1` says: I want to have `B` only in version `0.1` and package `A2` says, it needs `0.2`. Then there is a conflict, so you can not use (install) `A1` and `A2`. It can only be solved filing an issue with one of the packages (that one of them also checks and allows the other version of `B` to be used). Usually `A1` is easier, they just have to check that their package still works with the newer version of `B`.

Comment: I edited the question and added some output. The error is for all packages the same.

Answer (score 1):

The [Grisu.jl](https://github.com/JuliaAttic/Grisu.jl) package has no specific dependencies so there is rather no way how you could have some problems with it.

What usually helps is rebuilding the packages:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.build()
```

In most cases that will align everything back in order.

Sometimes on very rare occasions the Julia package repository gets corrupted (especially if you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in the middle of package installation and have bad luck) and in that case you will need to delete the `.julia` folder (which is located in your home directory)

Comment: I edited the question and added the output. The error is for all packages the same.

Comment: I removed the .julia directory. No I have to reinstall all packages :-( ... nevertheless JuMP did work and the next package JuMPeR caused the error. Removing JuMPeR didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I let the JuMPeR and MultiJuMP package away and all runs well.

Comment: JuMPer is three years old so basically it would introduce you an old dependency nightmare. I also remember having some compability issues with MultiJuMP in the past, but as of today it is only slightly over one year old.

Comment: But how to roll back if such a deprecated package has been installed?

Comment: try to remove with `Pkg.rm()` and than `Pkg.update()`